# On vSphere 4.1, what permission does a role need to edit the comment field of a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I've created a role with some limited access for my VWware infrastructure that is similar to the default Power User role. It appears that they do not have the ability to edit the comment field that is on Summary tab of the individual virtual machine. I can do it as an administrator.

What permission needs to be added to the role? I can't find anything like that in the list.

Answer (score 4):

It's 'Global'/'Manage Custom Attributes'.

Comment: It suddenly stopped working after we applied patches up to version ESXi 4.1.0, build 582267

Comment: Oh, so you just remove an answer approval there and then - wow, you totally understand how this site works... what a scummy thing to do.

Comment: Okay, then, @Chopper23, what was I supposed to do? It worked, and now it doesn't. Am I supposed to leave that as a an accepted answer? Open a new question?

Comment: @SBWorks: If it worked and now it doesn't what did _you_ change ?

Comment: @Iain We applied patches up to version ESXi 4.1.0, build 582267 on the hosts. I don't have a record of the previous version, but it was very close to the "raw" RTM version of ESXi 4.1.0 on all the hosts managed by that particular vSphere system

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the [vSphere Data Center Administration Guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_dc_admin_guide.pdf), Page 254, Table A-22. Virtual Machine Configuration Privileges.

Privilege Name: **Rename**

Description: Rename a virtual machine or ***modifies the associated notes*** of a virtual machine.

I tested this out with my current vSphere environment and it appears to be correct. Adding the **Global > Manage Custom Attributes** option no long gives you the ability to Edit notes but **Virtual Machine > Configuration > Rename** does give you the ability to edit notes (which is not actually the best solution for me in this case but I may be stuck with it).

Comment: It looks like v5.0 changed the permissions **again**